# Reading app.config of a VB6 project from a C# dll library

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, configurationmanager

I need to create a C# .NET DLL library that can read all the project configurations from a config file.

The main project was written in VB6, that calls my C# DLL library.

I created a test method that returns a cabled string and the call works correctly, so the VB6 to C# integration works.

My problem is that I use the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` class to read the configuration file (App.config). It works if the call come from a C# test project but it doesn't work if the call became from VB6 project.

I think that the problem is caused by VB6 that don't read App.config file as project configuration file, how I can do that?

Comment: config file is in xml format, i think xmlreader will help

Comment: A config file belongs to a .NET exe program, a VB6 app doesn't have one.  It is not like you can't give it one, name it yourvb6.exe.config where yourvb6 is the name of your VB6 exe file.  Extra hoops you have to jump through if you try to debug it in the VB6 IDE.  Still quite unclear why any of this would be useful when the VB6 code itself doesn't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved:
I tried to rename App.config in myVB6AppName.exe.config but it doesn't work.
The solution is including myVB6AppName.exe.config file in VB6 project as document. Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

If you are running VB6 in debug mode then remember to put your app.config as VB6.exe.config in folder where VB6.exe is.

Comment: no, I compiled and generated an exe file that is in the same path of the config file

Comment: So ConfigurationManager  should work fine in that case. Of course you have renamed your app.config to YourVB6ApplicationName.exe.config?

Comment: Consider using Process Monitor https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx to work out the actual path to the config file your application is trying to use.  It can save a lot of guessing